# XSD for XML with 1 elementname on 2 locations in

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd, sql-server-2014, xsd-validation

**Introduction**
Here below there are 2 very simplified versions of xml documents in a XML column on a SQL Server 2014 production server.
To start solving performances issues with this XML field I have created an XSD.
**Issue to resolve**
One issue is left over (see examples below):
- An element with the name "ProjectNr"
- is Always unique within a specific XML document
- But can be found on one of 2 different locations

**Question**
My question is two-folded:
- Can this issue be solved
- And if so, how?
**XML documents**
XML document, type 1:

```
<Project>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>1</Name>
    <ProjectNr>1</ProjectNr>
</Project><br/><br/>
```

XML document, type 2:

```
<Project>
    <ProjectNr>1</ProjectNr>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>1</Name>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The *all* compositor allows some flexibility in the ordering, and ensures that each element occurs with the desired amount of occurrences.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Project">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="ProjectNr" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Both documents are valid against the above schema (assuming the two `<br/>` in the question are typos, because document 1 would otherwise not be wellformed).